# Why is it possible to declare class type(in Java) or struct type(in C) before defining itself?

Tags: java, c

Here, I want to show some examples I wonder in C and Java

In C programming,

```
struct node{
    struct node *p_node;   //here
};
```

In Java programming,

```
public class node{
    public node nd= new node();  //here
}
```

Both of them are have common point of declaring `class(struct)` type before defining itself perfectly.

Over examples, you can see: `struct node *p` line  and `public node nd= new node();` line are described before '}' or ';'.

In this line, how they know the type despite of self type is not defined perfectly?

Comment: If not you could't do what you are doing. Note that in C nothing prevent you to declare `struct node;` before.

Comment: First of all, ask one question per language. I could explain you how that works for C (which has the notion of an *incomplete type*), but not for java. Although it's probably a somewhat similar concept, the java explanation WILL be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're merely allocating memory for a pointer to an instance of the structure. How much memory is needed for that is irrelevant at compile time, and at runtime will be known.

All that's needed when the field is allocated is knowing how much memory the pointer (or reference in Java, which is essentially similar in this context) takes, not how much memory will be needed to store whatever it's referring to.

And yes, that's overly simplified, especially in the case of Java. But that's the general idea.

Comment: "*You're merely allocating memory for an instance of the structure*" <- no idea for java, but that's not correct for C -- you're  just allocating memory for a **pointer** to the struct. (in fact, not even allocating it yet, just defining the contents of the struct to include a pointer ...)

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes. should have read "memory for a pointer to an instance of the structure".

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for C**:

C distiguishes between *complete* and *incomplete* types. A type can be introduced as an *incomplete* type and later be *completed* in the same translation unit. The difference is that for a *complete* type, the compiler knows the storage size -- for an *incomplete* type, it doesn't.

If you write

```
struct foo;
```

you already declared a type, but it's at this stage *incomplete*. With an incomplete type, it's possible to use *pointers* to that type, but not objects of the type itself. Now, in your example:

```
struct node{
    struct node *p_node;   //here
};
```

The *incomplete* type `struct node` is already known after the first line. Therefore, it's perfectly legal to use a *pointer* to that type in the second line. In the third line, the type is *complete* and you can now use objects of type `struct node`.

Side note: There's exactly one *incomplete type* in C that can't be completed: `void`. So you can always use pointers to void (`void *`), but never a `void` value.

Comment: thanks for answer, it was point that i was wondering. it was helpful